# How to force a php database query reload every 5sec without reloading page

Tags: php, jquery, html

I know this code below will force a page to reload every 5 seconds and display its contents in the assigned div

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    setInterval(function () {
        $('#comment_display').load('comments.php')
    }, 5000);
});
```

But I want to know if it's possible to replace the page URL with a div so that it force the div to reload every 5 seconds without reloading the page for example:

```
<div id="my_div" style="display:none;">
    <!-- run the database query to collect data from database and echo it out -->
</div>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        setInterval(function () {
            $('#comment_display').load($('#my_div'))
        }, 5000);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: use ajax and fetch data from server using databse query and replace your div every five seconds

Comment: @Poria... Please I am new to jQuery so I don't know how to do that, please can you give me a clue on how it's been done or paste a link where I can get its details

Comment: http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/beginners-guide-to-ajax-development-with-php here is tutorial

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## You can create an external file of PHP (file2.php). In that file you can write query. After every 5 seconds you can send request to that file (file2.php) and than you can replace result in desired div.

Example code
setInterval(function(){

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'file2.php',
    cache: false,
    success:function(data){
        $('#my_div').html(data);
    }

});
```

}, 5000);

Comment: Your answer is a long method of still achieving the same thing I did above